# I'm getting a really odd timing error, where something is executing before I believe it should

Tags: c, file, printing, io

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

int c, n, E, b, s, v, t, opt, valid = 0;
char current = '\0';
char previous = '\0';
FILE *fp;

/*  -n numbers lines
 *  -E appends a dollar sign to line ends
 *  -b numbers only non-blank lines
 *  -s squeezes multiple blank lines down to 1
 *  -v displays control chars, excluding tab
 *  -t includes tab in the above
 *  -e is the same as -E and -v
 */

int setFlags(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int op;
    while ((op = getopt(argc, argv, "nEbsvte")) != -1) {
        switch (op) {
            case 'n': {
                n = 1;
                break;
            } case 'E': {
                E = 1;
                break;
            } case 'b': {
                b = 1;
                break;
            } case 's': {
                s = 1;
                break;
            } case 'v': {
                v = 1;
                break;
            } case 't': {
                t = 1;
                break;
            } case 'e': {
                E = 1;
                v = 1;
                break;
            } case '?': {
                //fprintf(stderr, "Option `-%c` is not valid.\n", optopt);
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            } default: {
                abort();
            }
        }
    }
    opt = optind;

    if(n == 1) {
        b = 0;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int checkFile(char *path) {
    if (access(path, R_OK) == 0) {
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "cat: %s: %s\n", argv[i], strerror(errno));
        errno = 0;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}

int doPrint(char *path) {
    if (strcmp(path, "stdin") == 0) {
        fp = stdin;
    } else {
        if (checkFile(path) == 1) {
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        } else {
            fp = fopen(path, "r");
        }
    }
    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        putchar(c);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (setFlags(argc, argv) == 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "The program has terminated with an error.\n"
        "An invalid option was specified.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } else {
        if ((argc - opt) == 0) {
            doPrint("stdin");
        } else {
            for(int i = opt; i < argc; i++) {
                doPrint(argv[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting a really crazy bug, where my program outputs the error line in checkFile, before it finishes writing the contents of the file (always one chat before the end).

It's driving me insane, and no matter where I move that piece of code, it doesn't work as intended.

I'm sure the answer is probably trivial, but it has me stumped. I'd even thrown in sleeps and various other things just before output finished, and it would throw the error, THEN sleep, THEN print the final character.

Any help?

Comment: Ah, good ol' global variables. I don't even bother looking further.

Comment: I'm fairly inexperienced, so I don't really know how else to do it. I had the int c and FILE *fp inside doPrint; and moved them thinking it might work.

The rest of them only get set once, and just read from that point; it seemed like unnecessary work to keep throwing them around.

Comment: functions can take arguments. Take advantage of this fun fact.

Comment: But I'd have to type like, a million variables every time.

Comment: Your `fp` variable is only used in one function. Don't make it global when it doesn't have to be. Also, you could create a struct to hold all of the important things, and then pass around that struct (so there's only one variable to pass around).

Comment: Despite all this, I have no idea what your problem is. Can you give us some example input that you've tried, so we can test?

Comment: Minor comment - reuse your EXIT_??? when checking the output of checkFile instead of comparing to 1.

Comment: This line fails to compile: `fprintf(stderr, "cat: %s: %s\n", argv[i], strerror(errno));` `argv` was not passed into the function and is not globally accesdible.

Comment: @acarlow, that's my mistake, I had moved it to main briefly and put it back like that.


Otherwise, the output at the end of a file (when I purposely pass it a file that doesn't exist) might be 

    }  
cat: filename: File or directory does not exist  
}

Comment: Does `EXIT_FAILURE == 1`?  You're returning `EXIT_FAILURE` from `checkFile` but checking the return value against `1`.

Comment: EXIT_FAILURE does return 1, EXIT_SUCCESS returns 0

Comment: I don't see the problem you describe (after fixing the compiler error that acarlow pointed out).  You should describe the command you're using and give an example of the output you're seeing.

Comment: Is it failing when reading from an actual file or stdin or both?  If an actual file, is any other process accessing or writing to that file?

Comment: http://oi47.tinypic.com/35d185f.jpg
Is what I expect

http://oi47.tinypic.com/30svxbn.jpg
Is what I get

Comment: the input I used both times was stdin cat.c ffffffffff (so cat.c exists, ffffffffff doesn't.

Comment: Looks like a file buffering issue.  Try adding `fflush(stdout)` at the end of the `doPrint` function.

Comment: YEEEES

That was it, but what caused it? Am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: Variables for flags are uninitialized by default: I don't think this is a good idea. Also mixing 0 and 1 with EXIT_SUCCESS and EXIT_FAILURE is not a good idea for sustainability of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `printf`, `stdout` output is buffered by default.  This means it can be interleaved with other output, often from `stderr`.  `stderr` is unbuffered by default so that it's output is printed immediately as would normally be desired when an error occurs.

Interleaving can be fixed with judicious use of `fflush` or by turning off file buffering of `stdout` using `setbuf`.  Be sure to read the man pages for setbuf as there are some caveats.

In this case, adding fflush(stdout) at the end of the doPrint function should fix the "problem".

Comment: You're welcome, sometimes a picture is worth (more) than a thousand words :-)